# AutoLayout setting UILabel height to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a `UILabel` for item description amongst other views, all laid out using constraints in Interface Builder - you can see all relevant constraints in the image below. The number of lines is also set to `0`.

[image]

I haven't set the height constraint because I want the `UILabel` to resize based on the text it contains. Instead, what happens is right after

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

is called, the height of the `UILabel` gets set to `0`. Even if I don't set other text to the `UILabel`, it has a default value of *Item description* set in Interface Builder.

The item title label above is set the same way, but that one doesn't get squashed to `0`, so I'm a bit confused.

Anyone had any experience with such behaviour?

Comment: Do you have any AutoLayout constraint errors in the console? AutoLayout dropping some constraints due to conflicts?

Comment: I know that you don't want to hardcore a height to that UILabel, but what happens if you do? Do you get any AutoLayout constraint conflicts in the console?

Comment: I think you need to remove either the "top space to" or the "bottom space to". Otherwise the height is set by these constraints? I might be wrong though...

Comment: Hi Yaser. The *bottom space to* constraint is actually one that *depends on* the `UILabel`, i.e. the other view should move if the `UILabel` gets bigger

Comment: Solved it - setting the UILabel's vertical compression resistance priority to 1000 (default 750) seemed to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I managed to solve it by setting the `UILabel`'s `vertical compression resistance priority` to `1000` (default `750`) in Interface Builder.

[image]

Since my views are embedded in another view, and the parent view's bottom is dependent on the bottom of the lowest child view, I only speculate that the `UILabel` without a height constraint was getting squeezed in the process of laying out the views. Probably playing with priorities of other constraints somewhere down the chain would have yielded the same result, but I wasn't able to do it successfully. The solution above, however, worked, which is good enough in my case.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Set 3 constraint

1.Leading space to superview

2.Trailing space to superview

3.Top space to superview

then

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;

- (void) viewDidLoad{
   [self.lbl sizeToFit];
}
```

Comment: My constraints are like you suggested, except that I need the bottom one as well to push down other views if the label grows too tall. However, I managed to solve my problem by setting the UILabel's vertical compression resistance priority to 1000 (default 750).

Answer (score 1):

ctrl drag from the label to itself > select height > set the constant of the height to 0 and change equal (==) to greater than or equeal (>=)

Comment: This only made sure it's high enough for at least one line of text, but the rest is truncated, i.e. the label did not autoresize

Comment: Make sure the bottom constraint is correct, because this is the way to do it :-) Edit: try it by removing the bottom constraint to test it.

Comment: Ok so it seems you fixed it by changing the hugging to 1000. Was this thanks to adding my constraint or something that you added? Either way, check something as the correct answer.

Comment: For some reason, the bottom constraint (or their chain) was squeezing the label - I guess saying "don't squeeze me" (1000) did it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set 5 constraints on your label :

- Leading space to superview
- Trailing space to superview
- Vertical space to "Item"
- Vertical space to "Name"
- Height

Then add an IBOutlet in your controller on the constraint height (let's say labelHeight).

So in your viewDidLoad you will be able to set this constraint value:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeight;


- (void) viewDidLoad{
   [self.label sizeToFit];
   labelHeight.constant = self.label.frame.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AutoLayout` in this `UIViewController` can't satisfy all the `constraints` you have set, therefore it dismiss those on your `UILabel`, resulting in a compressed state. You  should have a look at the other `constraints` in your `UIViewController`, and set the `priority` of the `height contraint` to a higher number.