# How to set UILabel height to zero

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am using below constraints for a UILabel.
[image]

I am creating an outlet of label height and changing it to 0 on a condition but it is not decreasing the space. So please help me to set height 0 to delete the space of label.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271983/autolayout-setting-uilabel-height-to-zero

Comment: remove text from label . its height will be automatically set to zero .

Comment: did you try to hide the label ?? `label.isHidden = true`

Comment: You need to call `layoutIfNeeded` after setting height to be 0.

Comment: have you done your task or not @Gaurav Gupta

Comment: thank you @KKRocks, resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome . can i add this as my answer ? @GauravGupta

Answer (score 3):

Just **remove** text from label . its height will be automatically set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove** your **height constraint** and **text** from label it will automatically set its height to Zero.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height and one of the top or bottom constraints, then, within the same pane, change the content hugging priority to low priority.
Once the label has no text, it will have hight 0

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have View controller like this

[image]

And you want to set **Red Mark's Label** height to 0. Current it's height is

[image]

So if you want to programmatically set it's height to 0 draw an outlet and like this.
[image]

And as for example i just draw a button and in it's action i set it's height to 0.Trick is you have to set **[self.view layoutIfNeeded];**

just like this.

[image]

So when i clicked the button red button is hidden and the output just like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have an outlet like this in your viewcontroller:

```
 @IBOutlet var heightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

then you can set this height to zero by this following code:

```
heightConstraint.constant = 0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constraint of 0 to hide the label.

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
    [yourLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)]
)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged; please add some context to your answer.